# Как итерироваться по std::tuple и по variadic template одновременно?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, stl

У меня есть класс `Task<T>`, его метод `Run` возвращает результат типа T
Я хочу выполнить несколько разных задач и объединить их результаты в один tuple, как это сделать?

```
template <class... T>
auto GetResults (Task<T>... tasks) 
{
    std::tuple<T...> results;
    
    ([&](auto& task)
    {
        // как мне добавить результат к results ?
        // std::get<???>(results) = task.Run();
    } 
    (tasks), ...);

    return results;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте распаковку параметров:

```
template <typename... T>
auto GetResults (Task<T>... tasks) 
{
    return ::std::make_tuple(tasks.Run()...);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Лямбда не нужна.

```
return std::tuple{tasks.Run()...};
```